# SQL Server Pattern Matching string - regex

Tags: sql-server, regex, string, pattern-matching

I need to select all columns in a table where value should be in below format

```
DIGITS_STRING_DIGITS.STRING
```

eg:

```
(123_tre_345.txt)
```

I am new to SQL Server. Is there a way to write query to read like this?

Answer (score 1):

In order to exploit the full potential of regular expressions in SQL server, you have to implement `CLR` procedures.

The `LIKE` statement provides [some](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql) of the commonest regular expression features and, despite not being very elegant because of the missing quantifiers, it should be enough to handle this case:

```
SELECT Field
FROM Table
WHERE Field LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][_][a-z][a-z][a-z][_][0-9][0-9][0-9].txt'
```